# Change color of selected text in a div using bootstrap & color picker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, color-picker

I have a div which has some long text

For e.g. "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."

I just want to change the color of "sit amet" upon selection through colorpicker(using colpicker.js for the color palette).

Currently what I have is:

**Html code**:

```
<div id="editor">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
```

**Script**:

```
$('#editor').css('color', '#'+hex);
```

But the above code sets the color of the whole div content to the color set. I just want to change the color of the highlighted text.

Comment: wouldn't it be better to surround `sit amet` by ex. span with class or id attribute and change the color by this reference?

Comment: You can only target elements with CSS (and pseudo-elements, such as `::first-letter `, `::first-line`), to target the phrase/words "sit amet" they'd first have to be wrapped by an element, with JavaScript on the client-side, or a server-side language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap selected text into some wrapepr, and unwrap it when unselected. Here is working example:

```js
function selectText(hexColor) {
    var selection = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    var selectedText = selection.extractContents();
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.style.backgroundColor = hexColor;
    span.className = 'selected-text';
    span.appendChild(selectedText);
    selection.insertNode(span);
}

function unselectText(){
    $('#text-box').find('.selected-text').contents().unwrap();;
}

$(document).on('mouseup', function () {
    selectText('#f90');
});

$(document).on('mousedown', function () {
    unselectText();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text-box">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
```

Run code snippet to view it in action

Comment: Thanks Vitalii, this solution works for me. Thanks for a quick reply

Comment: I tested some more, and found that if I reselect the previous selection, then the action doesn't happen correctly. If i am inserting a span everytime, it should somehow override the previous   span which we added. How do I do tht?

Answer (score 2):

This just selects 'sit amet' string

jQuery:

```
$('#editor').replace('sit amet', '<span class="col">sit amet</span>');
$('span.col').css({'color': '#' + hex});
```

If you want to style a string that is not fixed:

```
var string = 'your selected string';
$('#editor').replace(string, '<span class="col">' + string + '</span>');
$('span.col').css({'color': '#' + hex});
```

Comment: This will work, but I would need to handle the cases where the selected string for eg: "sit amet" is appearing multiple times in the div content. I cannot depend on the characters selected. I have to get the position of the selected text and then replace them with coloured span. But thanks anyways for ur reply :)