# Use :nth-child to style certain words

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Can I use `:nth-child` to select (and style) particular words in given HTML element? For example:

```
<h2 class="site-description">Four word long title</h2>
```

I'd like to change style -- change `font-size` and `font-style` of the *first two* words and make *two following* word wrap to another line -- without need to change HTML, to which I don't have access.

Is this possible with `:nth-child`?

If this is completely bad approach, then is there any other option to achieve this?

Comment: `nth-child` won't work for this case. Maybe `:first-word` can be used for the first word but if you want both the first two words then a HTML change (either manually or using JS) seems unavoidable.

Comment: does not look like it, http://webdesignerhut.com/style-first-letter-word-line-and-paragraph-with-css-and-jquery/

Comment: Even if :nth-child did target text nodes, you only have one text node in this example, not four.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it wont work with  `:nth-child`

### Because nth-child works only on child tags not on characters of string

if you cant change html try with jquery -
or refer this

### [Change color of selected text in a div using bootstrap & color picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27705152/change-color-of-selected-text-in-a-div-using-bootstrap-color-picker)

You can try this if you can edit html:

Separate the characters with span and apply css on that spans

Hope Helps

Comment: _"...without need to change HTML, to which I don't have access."_

Answer (score 1):

nth-child is applying on an html tag.

here you only have one html tags.
The possible would be to create a small js function or add a html tags for each of the words.
I would use the javascript solution.

Otherwise you could look with http://letteringjs.com/ if you are willing to accept another library.